# What would I need in a Rails 3 controller to process incoming emails and insert them into the database?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I'm trying to set up my RoR 3 application to receive emails and then process those emails and insert them into the database.

In my application, I have a "jobs" controller. Users can create jobs. I also have a "comments" controller. Users can create comments on jobs.

Here is (part of) what I have in my comments controller:

```
def new
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @comment = @job.comments.build
end

def create
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @comment = @job.comments.build(params[:comment])
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id
  @comment.commenter = current_user.login
 if @comment.save
    redirect_to @job
  else
    render :action => "new"
 end
end
```

When users add a comment, the admin receives an email.
When admins add a comment, users receive an email.
(This is already functioning.)

I'm using [Cloudmailin](http://cloudmailin.com/) to help me receive incoming mail. I've set up the Cloudmailin address to point to http://myapp.com/incoming_mails.

```
class IncomingMailsController < ApplicationController

  require 'mail' 
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

    def create
      another_comment = Comment.create(:title => 
      params[:subject], :body => params[:plain])

      render :text => 'success', :status => 200 #status of 404 rejects mail

    end
end
```

Looking at the above comment controller, it looks like I'll need the job_id, current_user.id, and current_user.login.

Here's what I am having trouble sorting out: what goes in my "incoming_mails" controller? How can I make sure that when a user responds via email that the controller in "incoming_mails" is able to find the job_id and the current_user.id (or user_id) and then insert that information into the database?

I'm thinking that I'll need to grab the user's email address and then also have the job_id in the subject line...hmmm....

Does anyone have experience setting up incoming mail processing in Rails 3?

Comment: The email has a subject with the case number. I think I could use the case_number to find the job_id. To find the user_id, I think I could use the email address (the "from" in the incoming email). And then the body of the comment should be whatever comes above "== ADD YOUR REPLY ABOVE THIS LINE ==". Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes. That seems to be how it's done in other apps, with one exception: they normally have the Reply-to of the Outbound emails set to the case number, but I don't think you'll have to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I saw in a few examples that they had the "case number" in the reply-to. This is one example: http://blog.teambox.com/handling-incoming-email

Answer (score 3):

There's a few ways to do this. A common technique is to set the from/reply_to as a custom email address that allows you to do a lookup of the original object. Something like:

```
 class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :commentable
   has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
   before_validation :generate_token, :on => :create

   validates :token, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
   attr_accessible :token

   private

   def generate_token
     ...
   end
 end
```

Email is sent with a from/reply_to address like [token]@msg.yoursite.com
(You can also use a comments+[token_or_id]@msg.yoursite.com if you'd like - see the :disposable param supplied by cloudmailin)

```
 class IncomingMailsController < ApplicationController

   def create
     @comment = Comment.find_by_token(params[:to].split('@')[0])
     @comment.comments.create(:body => params[:plain])
     render :text => 'success', :status => 200
   end
 end
```

If you go the [token]@msg.yoursite.com then you have to setup your dns records properly as described [here](http://docs.cloudmailin.com/custom_domains).

Another option is to store content in the headers of the email. Maybe your headers would look something like this:

```
 X-YOURAPP-OBJECT-ID = 44
 X-YOURAPP-OBJECT-TYPE = Job
 X-YOURAPP-TARGET-ASSOC = comments
 X-YOURAPP-TARGET-ATTR = body
```

Then your controller would look more like this:

```
 class IncomingMailsController < ApplicationController

   def create
     headers = Mail::Header.new(params[:message])
     object= headers[:x_yourapp_object_type].constantize.find(headers[:x_yourapp_object_id])
     object.send(headers[:x_yourapp_target_assoc]).create(headers[:x_yourapp_target_attr] => params[:plain])
     render :text => 'success', :status => 200
   end
 end
```

The advantage to doing it this way is that it's completely generic. You can have comments on jobs, comments on comments, or whatever. If you create another model that you also want to allow email reply on... just update the headers and you're set. The only issue is that you have to be careful of these headers being stripped out by mail clients. Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086323/custom-email-header) for more information about that.

I'm currently using the first technique and it's working very well. However, I'll be refactoring and trying the second technique at the end of this week.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is a full answer but let me give it a quick shot and I can update it when I have a little more time.

Firstly I would start by having the job perhaps as part of the to address. Use comment+1@domain.com with 1 signifying that this is job number one. This part after the plus is called the is the disposable part in CloudMailin (params[:disposable]. The users email address can then be taken from the message body either using params[:from] or Mail.new(params[:message]).from (sometimes the from address given to the SMTP server is different to the one in the header)

Next you have the comment itself which can simply be the plain param.

This gives something like the following:

```
def create
  @job = Job.find(params[:disposable])
  if comment = @job.comments.create(:text => params[:plain], :commenter => User.find_by_email(params[:from])
    render :text => 'Success', :status => 401
  else
    render :text => comment.errors.inspect, :status => 422, :content_type => 'text/plain'
 end
```

I hope that helps. It's a bit rough but hopefully it gives the right idea.

Comment: Just to add to some of the other comments. The way that teambox process incoming emails is great to take a look at. Have a look at the code too as it certainly helps (I've written some of the teambox email code but other parts really helped me). I've also up-voted Mike's answer although be aware you cannot be sure that mail clients will keep the headers.

Comment: thanks, that is definitely something to watch out for. I'm gonna be testing the second solution I gave in a production environment this week. Will post back once I have results.

Comment: In the original "comments_controller.rb", I have "@comment.user_id = current_user.id". I see you put ":commenter => User.find_by_email(params[:from])" to get the "commenter". How could I grab the user_id in this new "create"?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the lookup of the user model in order to find the email address so you will still have to say User.find_by_email(params[:from]) to get the user and then just call .id to find the user_id from this so: @comment.user_id User.find_by_email(params[:from]).id. or in the create statement :user_id => .User.find_by_email(params[:from]).id. I just used commenter in place of the relationship user and assigned the whole model rather than working directly with the id as rails can do that for us.